# Material on Coherent Control

Tags: optics, resource-recommendations, quantum-optics

I'm looking into [coherent control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_control) for a new module, I was hoping to find some material that is beginner friendly be a book, website, video etc. . All books I have found on my own all expect some knowledge in the field and whilst in the end I'm happy to make my way through the books I found if there is anything I can read before them to get a good understanding it'd help a lot. So in essence I want to find out what coherent control is and what's being done in the field today.